# sending multiple emails using queue - laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel

I need to send bulk emails using Laravel queue and jobs.  If I understood, my method this way should dispatch 1 job where all the emails are fetched and send it one by one going through the foreach loop, right? Somehow, only one email got send. And when I check the message, it appears the recipient message is in this format - "test2@gmail.com" <test1@gmail.com>. Only test1 email account received the email. I am not sure what causing it. Thank you for your help.

**Controller**

```
$body = $request->body;
        $titleName = $request->subject;
        
        $job = (new \App\Jobs\SendQueueEmail($body, $titleName))
                ->delay(now()->addSeconds(2)); 

        dispatch($job);
```

**Job**

```
public function handle(Request $request)
    {

        $emailsAlumni = ['test1@gmail.com', 'test2@gmail.com'];
        $date = Carbon::now()->format('d M Y');

        $data = [
            "body" => $this->body,
            "date" => $date
        ];

        foreach ($emailsAlumni as $email) {
            Mail::send('main.admin.email.general', $data, function ($message) use ($email) {
                $message->to($email);
                $message->subject('title');
            });
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to loop whole Mail instance you can just try it as

```
Mail::send('main.admin.email.general', $data, function ($message) use ($emailsAlumni) {
            $message->to($emailsAlumni);
            $message->subject('title');
        });
```

Comment: Note that this will send 1 email to all recipients, with everybody's email address visible in the 'To:' field.

Comment: You can use ->bcc() of course for the blind carbon copies